# How to simulate pressing the END key

Tags: javascript

I have a javascript function that gets called from an aspx.vb file:

```
using ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Me, Page.GetType, "Script", "pressKey();", True)
```

and I need the `pressKey` function to simulate pressing the <kbd>END</kbd> key as if the user pressed it on their keyboard.

Comment: By e.keycode and match the syn event.

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/596481/is-it-possible-to-simulate-key-press-events-programmatically

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible to simulate key press events programmatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/596481/is-it-possible-to-simulate-key-press-events-programmatically)

Answer (score 1):

The charCode for the End key is 35. CSS tricks has a good list of character codes: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/javascript/javascript-keycodes/

**Here is the Vanilla JS solution:**

```
var keyboardEvent = document.createEvent("KeyboardEvent");
var initMethod = typeof keyboardEvent.initKeyboardEvent !== 'undefined' ? 
"initKeyboardEvent" : "initKeyEvent";


keyboardEvent[initMethod](
               "keydown", // event type : keydown, keyup, keypress
                true, // bubbles
                true, // cancelable
                window, // viewArg: should be window
                false, // ctrlKeyArg
                false, // altKeyArg
                false, // shiftKeyArg
                false, // metaKeyArg
                35, // keyCodeArg : unsigned long the virtual key code, else 0
                0 // charCodeArgs : unsigned long the Unicode character associated with the depressed key, else 0
);
document.dispatchEvent(keyboardEvent);
```